# parameterized sql query for zipcode and radius not working

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table

persons that has a column zipcode

that is related to a zipcodes table that has the zipcode as the id and a column for latitudes and longitudes.

I found a series of functions that calculate distance on a sphere (basically for zipcodes) using latitude and longitude. I'm rather new to sql and was wondering how to use these functions in a stored procedure.

latitude function:

```
        ALTER Function [dbo].[LatitudePlusDistance](@StartLatitude Float, @Distance Float) Returns Float
As
Begin
    Return (Select @StartLatitude + Sqrt(@Distance * @Distance / 4766.8999155991))
End
```

longitude function:

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[LongitudePlusDistance]
(
    @StartLongitude float,
    @StartLatitude float,
    @Distance float
)
    RETURNS Float
    AS
begin

RETURN (select @startLongitude + sqrt(@Distance * @Distance/(4784.39411916406*Cos(2*@StartLatitude/114.591559026165)*Cos(2*@StartLatitude/114.591559026165))))
END
begin

RETURN (select @startLongitude + sqrt(@Distance * @Distance/(4784.39411916406*Cos(2*@StartLatitude/114.591559026165)*Cos(2*@StartLatitude/114.591559026165))))
END`
```

calculate distance function

```
    `ALTER Function [dbo].[CalculateDistance]
    (@Longitude1 Decimal(8,5),
    @Latitude1   Decimal(8,5),
    @Longitude2  Decimal(8,5),
    @Latitude2   Decimal(8,5))
Returns Float
As
Begin
Declare @Temp Float

Set @Temp = sin(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * sin(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) + cos(@Latitude1/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Latitude2/57.2957795130823) * cos(@Longitude2/57.2957795130823 - @Longitude1/57.2957795130823)

if @Temp > 1
    Set @Temp = 1
Else If @Temp < -1
    Set @Temp = -1

Return (3958.75586574 * acos(@Temp) )

End`
```

i tried something like this...

```
    Declare @Longitude Decimal(8,5)
Declare @Latitude Decimal(8,5)

Select  @Longitude = Longitude,
        @Latitude = Latitude
From    ZipCodes
Where   ZipCode = '20013'

    Declare @Distance int

Select  persons.personName, ZipCodes.City,  dbo.CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, ZipCodes.Longitude, ZipCodes.Latitude) As Distance
From    persons
        Inner Join ZipCodes
            On persons.zipcode = ZipCodes.ZipCode
Order By dbo.CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, ZipCodes.Longitude, ZipCodes.Latitude)
    WHERE dbo.CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, ZipCodes.Longitude, ZipCodes.Latitude) As Distance <= @Distance
```

I tried this just to filter the persons outside a parameterized search radius and it doesn't work. says there's an "incorrect syntax near the keyword "where"

that doesn't even include my desire to throw in a parameter for the zipcode so instead of:

where zipcode = '20013'

i'd like something like:

where zipcode = @zipcode

but it says i need to declare the zscalar variable @zipcode and no matter where i try to do that...i keep getting the same error

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

you are using "order by" clause before "where" that is one of the problem and you can't use alias in where condition is another problem . please try following query :

```
Declare @Longitude Decimal(8,5)
Declare @Latitude Decimal(8,5)

Select  @Longitude = Longitude,
        @Latitude = Latitude
From    ZipCodes
Where   ZipCode = '20013'

Declare @Distance int
set @Distance = 5

Select  persons.personName, ZipCodes.City,  dbo.CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude,    ZipCodes.Longitude, ZipCodes.Latitude) As Distance
From    persons Inner Join ZipCodes On persons.zipcode = ZipCodes.ZipCode
WHERE dbo.CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, ZipCodes.Longitude, ZipCodes.Latitude) <= @Distance
Order By dbo.CalculateDistance(@Longitude, @Latitude, ZipCodes.Longitude, ZipCodes.Latitude)
```

Comment: tried it. i took out the order by clause altogether. didn't seem to work. didn't ask me for the @distance input either.

Comment: just edited the query . Added set @Distance = 5 . from there you can set your distance .

Comment: still doesn't work :( i should say (hopefully this will help diagnose the problem) i'm using vb web developer and i'm just trying this all in the "new query" wizard. would that make a difference?

Comment: no error, it just doesn't ask me to input a distance and no rows are returned